# Embed static library in dynamic library clang

Tags: c++, linker, clang, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a project with one Shared library (Engine) and one Executable (Game). Nevertheless, my engine is using some others library like spdlog. I'm wondering if there is a way to link only my shared library with all the other libraries.

Currently, if i'm using spdlog in Engine (to create a Log class for example) and after that use this Log class in the game. I need to link spdlog also in the game.

So i'm wondering if there is a way to kind of "embed" these libraries inside my shared libraries to avoid all these linking inside my exe?

By the way, i'm using clang on multiple platform ,currently windows and linux.

Comment: A shared/dynamic library is a separate linked entity, much like an executable program. But, being a separate entity, distinct from the executables that uses the library, its dependencies (libraries that the shared library link with) are not exported from the shared library. If you need to use a third-party library in both your own shared library and your executable, then you need to link with that third-party library to both the executable and shared library.

Comment: With that said, if the third-party library is also a shared library, the OS will only load it once anyway. It might be mapped to multiple processes, but only one copy of the shared library should be in memory.

Comment: Well currently it is a static library i would like to "embed". But it's more for pratical reason, it doesn't prevent me from coding. I'm asking that for easier use.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if libspdlog has been linked with `-fPIC` (which is unlikely). In that case you could add spdlog when linking your library:

```
gcc -o libmylib.so ... -Wl,--whole-archive path/to/libspdlog.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

If library has been linked without `-fPIC` you'll get an error like "relocation ... can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIС".

Comment: Yes i saw the flag --whole-archive for gcc. But i wanted to know if something like that existed for clang compiler?

Comment: @miyoku Note the `-Wl` prefix - it tells that this is a _linker_ flag so works in the same way to GCC and Clang.